# Des Serialize file in android

Tags: android, serialization

I have a fairly rare issue.

I have a fext file to parse and generate a model android data (there are three classes) and serialized to file. This is done in android application project I have.

With myself from my mobile application deserialized the file correctly.

Instead try to do this in another mobile with the same apk file and it fails.

Any idea of what is the reason behind this???

Regards and any ideas I can be useful .

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"?  Please show us the code you use, the content of the file and any applicable error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exception to read the file serialization...

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: libcore.util.ZoneInfo
```

In the class to serialize one member is type of "Calendar"

```
  import java.util.Calendar;
  Calendar date
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered the cause of failure.

It's a java bug when serializing Calendar with multithreading

Now I keep time with a variable type "long" "Calendar.getTimeInMillis"

Good Luck

bY kLvin